# Why isn’t UIViewController’s view typed as id?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have always thought it a pity to have the `UIViewController`’s view explicitly typed as `UIView`, because the controller subclasses have their own view types and have to recast the `UIView` to the correct type:

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController {}
@implementation MyController

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [(MyView*)self.view doThisOrThat];
}

// Or define a custom accessor:
- (MyView*) myView {
    return (MyView*) [self view];
}
```

This feels dumb. If the `UIViewController`’s view was typed as `id`, we could get away without the casting. As the view controllers are made for subclassing, this would seem like a natural design choise. What would be the drawbacks? (Or is there an easier way to overcome the explicit view type problems?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `id` just because it allows you to call any method without compiler warning is a bad idea, to my taste. You can easily call a method which is not defined even in your view subclass without any compile time warning, later leading to a crash.

I would make another `IBOutlet MyView* myView` and connect my view not only to `view` but also to `myView`.

Comment: It bugs me to have two different outlets for the same object just to get around typing issues, but thank you, that’s a legitimate viewpoint.

Comment: I agree it's not ideal, but it would be better than lots of explicit casting, again to my taste.